# Firebase Cloud Function get inner child of child from list (nodeJs)

Tags: node.js, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-admin

Trying to get all the 'Token' values from each child inside the Infos Child, when the database event onUpdate trigger ,but it seems I'm wrong
any solutions?
[image: Table]

```
   var allTokens = [];

    await admin.database().ref('/Roles/Livreurs').once("value", function (snapshot) {

        snapshot.forEach(function (childSnapShot) {

            childSnapShot.forEach(function (innerChild) {
                var token = innerChild.val().Token;
                allTokens.push(token);
            });
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only need `forEach` if you don't know the keys at a level in your JSON, in your case that only applies to the user IDs. For any level where you know the key, you can use `child(thatkey)` to get at that child snapshot.

So I think you're looking for:

```
let allTokens = await admin.database().ref('/Roles/Livreurs').once("value", function (snapshot) {
    var result = [];
    snapshot.forEach(function (userSnapShot) {
        var token = userSnapShot.child("Infos/Token").val();
        result.push(token);
    });
    return result;
});
```

And then use it as

Comment: I don't understand.. I got no errors, and still I don't receive any notifications . when RestaurantsOrders/{pushId} is updated  the func should be triggered , I'll update my post now sir please have a look

Comment: Sorry, but you'll have to isolate what you ask about here in a question. My answer shows what you're doing wrong in reading data from the database. You should be able to check if that fixes the data loading problem.

Comment: Alright sir, how can I println to see if I got the token ?  console.log() and then firebase deploy?

Comment: Yes, that'd be one way. You can also [use the emulator suite](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite) to test it locally, which will be a lot faster (after the initial setup).

Comment: Note that I'm completely guessing here, as you haven't shown the code for any logging. I highly recommend reading [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as the guidance in there increases the chance we can help. Note that you can also use the Admin SDK in a local Node.js script, which means you can test just the code that you shared in your question so far - and thus isolate whether the problem is in there or elsewhere.

Comment: I just realized I don't get all the tokens variables, you sure sir this is the correct way ?

Comment: Yes, I'm quite sure that this code will read all tokens under `/Roles/Livreurs` and add them to `allTokens`. What happens with those tokens, I can't say though as you didn't share any code that uses this function. I just edited my answer to show how you get the tokens outside of this code.